# JSON Date Format PHP

Tags: php, json

I am working on web service and I am sending json data on clients API, the client gave me the example of json date format that will be accepted by their API.

```
 {
   "DateTime":"\/Date(928120800000+0800)\/"
 }
```

I wonder whats the equivalent of that date on php.. I've been searching on net for 30 minutes and didn't get the answer.

Our client used .net on their API.

My question is whats the equivalent of that date in php and how can I convert normal time in that format using php. e.g date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: You spoke with the client but they didn't tell you what kind of number this is? If the date is supposed to be `Mon, 31 May 1999 03:20:00` then it's the unix time with microseconds.

Comment: In addition to what @h2ooooooo noted, it's likely a timezone appended on the end of it (the `+0800`)

Comment: It's impossible to know for sure what a given number represents if the API documentation doesn't explain it. It's clearly not a Unix timestamp. If it was 1000 times a Unix timestamp it'd be `Mon, 31 May 1999 03:20:00 +0000` but it doesn't make the least sense to append a time zone.

Comment: As about the .NET hint, it seems that C# uses `new DateTime(2011, 6, 10)` and Visual Basic uses `Dim thisDate As Date = #03/15/2008#` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Comment: And to add more fun, you need to escape forward slashes for no obvious reason...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to format DateTime to .NET JSON Date format:

https://github.com/webapix/dot-net-json-date-formatter

```
use \Webapix\DotNetJsonDate\Date;

$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d H:i:s', '1999-05-31 11:20:00',
    new \DateTimeZone('+0800')
);

Date::toJsonDate($dateTime); // returns '/Date(928120800000+0800)/'
```